# React router, how to restore state after browser back button?

Tags: reactjs, browser, router, browser-history

I'm trying to figure out how to make my React SPA app maintain state when the user navigates with the back/forward browser buttons. E.g. the user is filling a form, then he moves back and forward and the form is automatically restored.

I reviewed many JavaScript routers around but none seem to address this issue properly... (or even at all).

Currently I'm using React Router 4 and this is the pattern I'm adopting:

1. when programmatically leaving the page, I first save current page's state with `history.replace(this.state)`; then I move out of the page with `history.push(newLocation)`
2. when a page component is created (`componentWillMount`) I check for `this.props.location.state !== undefined` and if so, I restore it with `this.setState(this.props.location.state)`

My question is: is the above pattern correct? suggested? Is there any better and widely adopted way?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history), both `history.push` and `history.replace` have the same function signature, `(path, [state])`. Then why are you using `history.replace` with state as 2nd parameter ? I think you must use simply `history.push(newLocation, this.state)` instead of the 2 calls

Comment: is the state parameter in `history.push` to be meant as "the state of the current page that will get restored in case of back button" or is it "the state that the new page will take" ? This is very confusing.

Comment: More like the second one I guess.. It's some state that you want to pass to the next page. So in your case, I think you can pass around the state of the form

Comment: ok @Dane got it, I pass the state the new page will get. What I don't understand is how I deal with the back button. When the user clicks it, I don't have any chance to run any code. Should I use `history.replaceState()` after every `this.setState()` to keep the current state updated (synchronized)?

Comment: I think you would have to use some state management library like Redux to do that, cos maintaining state across routes is not exactly something suppoted by RR.. You pass states to next pages, but that's about it

Answer (score 19):

after a while I found a reasonable workaround:

- in react, after every `this.setState()` I keep state synchronized with history using `window.history.replaceState({ key: history.location.key, state: this.state})`
- when a "page" component is mounted or refreshed (`willMount` and `willReceiveProps`) I check for state in `props.params.location.state`: if there is one, I do restore it; if there is none I create a fresh new state.
- when navigating on the same page, I do not use routes, I just use `this.setState` and `window.history.pushState`
- when navigating outside of the page, I just use routes and avoid to pass anything in the state

This solution seems to work nicely, the only minor cons are:

- state must be serializable
- `this.setState` is a pitfall because it's asynchronous, you cannot use `this.state` after it, unless you do trickery.
- initial empty state must be provided by a function to be used during the restore or init phase, it can't just stay in the `constructor()` of the `Component`
- in Firefox, automatic scroll restoration after the back button works randomly, don't know why, but Chrome and Edge are ok.

Overall I have written a `PageComponent` that extends `Component` that does all the init/restoration work; it also overrides `this.setState` to make it syncs automatically with history and avoids the asynchronous annoyances.

Comment: This suggestion helps a lot. To resolve the setState syncing issue, you can pass a callback which than replaces the state. `this.setState({ a: "b" }, function() { console.log("replace state here") });`

Comment: I like this approach. However, as far as I understood history.state has size limitations. What I did:
After each setState I cache the result in sessionStorage, 2. Each time the component mounts I check if ```history.action==="POP"``` and if ```true``` I load the cached state version instead of fetching from server. Works so far but current drawback I see is that if the users reloads the page with F5 or browser button the history.action is still ```POP```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the session storage instead of state. Just replace the `useState()` function and use the `useSessionStorage()`.

For example:

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useSessionStorage("state_key", "initial_value")


const handleSomeChangeOnState = (event: any) => {
  setMyState("new_value")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` and check if there has been a change in value of `props.location.key` to restore states only when the user navigates with browser buttons.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,states){
         if ((typeof props.location !== 'undefined') &&
             (typeof props.location.state !== 'undefined') &&
              (states.location_key !== props.location.key)) {
             let newState = props.location.state;
             newState.location_key = props.location.key;
             return newState;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a React component un-mounts, the state is also destroyed. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

You can use Redux https://redux.js.org/, the state management library to extract your state from the component. This way, even when your component unmounts, the state will persist as long as the Redux Provider remains mounted (which should be the case if you set your provider at the top level of your application).

Redux slice example

```
const mySlice = createSlice({
  initialState: { textFieldA: '' },
  name: "textFields",
  reducers: {
    setTextFieldA(state, action) {
      state.textFieldA = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

You'll want to create a Redux store and add your reducer to it.

In your React Component, use the redux slice.

```
import { setTextFieldA } from './slice'

function MyComponent() {
  const { textFieldA } = useSelector((state) => state.myReducer);

  function onTextFieldAChange(text) {
    dispatch(setTextFieldA(text));
  }

  // render component
}
```

Now if `MyComponent` unmounts, the state will persist in the store if I navigate away to a different part of my application. When I rerender MyComponent, `textFieldA` will remain the same as I left it.

Answer (score -1):

i thought about this problem too,
For example you have multi-step form and you want to navigate between steps by browser controls too. As result you have to use router for storing activeStep, but you don't want to share it in browser URL. The solution is store step in router state:

```js
const location = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();

const onSubmit = useCallback(() => {
  history.push({
    ..location,
    state: {
      activeStep: 1
    }
  });
}, [...]);
```

As result your step will restore event after page refreshing, but you can't share step to other user. It's perfect.

The next problem is store form data between steps. We can't store it in router state, too. I've chosen for it sessionStorage. It has similar properties like router state. As result you have to update session storage fro example on submit and retrieve data on init form:

```js
const location = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();
const [initData] = useState(getFormDataFromStorage());

const onSubmit = useCallback(() => {
  saveFormDataToStorage(...);
  history.push({
    ..location,
    state: {
      activeStep: 1
    }
  });
}, [...]);
```

i prepared the [demo](https://sin9k.com/stepper) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Sin9k/react-router-dom-tricks#perfect-multistep-form) where you can test it and details you can find [here](https://youtu.be/-j8s0RNOZ8U) ([RU](https://youtu.be/d3SH1H-shlg))