# How to save react states on browser back button?

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components/pages **Home, page1, page2** and I'm sending props from home and calling page1

```
<Link
  style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
  to={{
    pathname: "/page1",
    Props: { categoryID: val.id, categoryName: val.name }
  }}
/>;
```

Then page 1 is getting these props in the constructor and defining states

```
class BuyerItems extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          id: props.location.aboutProps.categoryID,
          name: props.location.aboutProps.categoryName,
          gigs:[],
        }
        this.getGigs();
      }
```

Now from here if I go to **page2** through link and then press browser back button it gives following error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryID' of undefined**

How to get these props or states from history and where to write that code?
[image: error]

Comment: clicking the back button will cause the page to reload hence all the state which is saved in browsers memory will be lost, to prevent that you need to persist the state you can do that in localStorage

Comment: can you please explain how to persist these states

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495696/react-router-how-to-restore-state-after-browser-back-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only issue is that you need to pass your props in the state object as @Manu suggested & not as a random property name like you are doing now. I made a repo for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dawn-pfd8z?file=/src/Main.js). as you can see the properties passed in the react-router's state object are persisting after pressing back button in sandbox's window, but the ones I put as props are not.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing data through links like that since it can be inconsistent; A better way would be to push your data to `url` as query parameters,so for example your page2 will have a `url` similar to

```
{baseUrl}/page2?id=someCategoryId&name=someCategoryName
```

then in your rusulting component you could fetch and parse the query:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
```

better yet refer this: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters